# How to select individual ListElement from the ListModel and process it in ListView

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a list model which contains some list elements.

Say for example:

import QtQuick 2.0

```
ListModel {
    id: fruitModel

    ListElement {
        name: "Apple"
        cost: 2.45
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Orange"
        cost: 3.25
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Banana"
        cost: 1.95
    }
}
```

Now I create a component and ListView to delegate and view the model.

```
 Component {
        id: fruitDelegate
        Row {
            spacing: 10
            Text { text: name }
            Text { text: '$' + cost }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: fruitModel
        delegate: fruitDelegate
    }
```

The above example is from Qt documentation.

But Qt documentation fails to mention how to select or get hold of a single element in the model and process just that element.

I would like to select one element and process it and finish the ListView, even though my list model has several listElements.

Can someone know how to select a single or couple of ListElements (Not all of them) from the list model.

Comment: `I would like to select one element and process it and finish the ListView`. What does that mean ?

Comment: @GrecKo...The ListModel contains 3 ListElements and I would like to know how to select one ListElement from the ListModel and process only that Element in the ListView.

Answer (score 2):

> But Qt documentation fails to mention how to select or get hold of a
>   single element in the model and process just that element.

I'd say it is mentioned fairly clear:

```
object get(int index)
```

> Returns the item at index in the list model. This allows the item data
>   to be accessed or modified from JavaScript

EDIT: Keep in mind, in addition to "select" an individual model item with `get()`, when you are using a view, each delegate will be automatically "selecting" the underlying item.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't want to touch JavaScript, I would like to do everything with Qt and QML.

Comment: @Circuitdude QML is JS. It's json-like markup with js scripting.

Comment: The other alternative is to use C++, but `ListModel` doesn't even have a public C++ API. If you use QML, you use JS, there is no way around that.

Comment: You have to clarify your question. There is nothing in the question saying you want to do that in C++. Among other things there are tons of info about integration QML and C++. You can start from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html)